# soft timeout crashes main instance of Scala program using Scala^Z3

Tags: scala, timeout, z3

I'm using **Scala^Z3** for using **Z3** within **Scala**. Now for some experiments I'm doing, which involves solving problems which become very complex, in order to cancel the current calculation.

I have tried a soft timeout, which from the documentation sounded like the perfect option for me. I used it like this:

```
config.setParamValue("SOFT_TIMEOUT", "5200")
```

However, instead of just canceling the calculation, it crashes my whole Scala program with the error message `"Error: invalid usage"`.

I've tried to use concurrency like Futures in order to prevent the main program to die, but then I can't use **Z3** in my program anymore until I restart it, because I get the error message `"Error: invalid usage"` immediately.

Is there something I misunderstood about soft timeouts?

Thanks in advance!

Yours,
Stefan Tiran

Answer (score 0):

The names of options have been refactored in the 4.3.2 release, so the option is now called "smt.soft_timeout", see [the answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28162661/4007786) for more details on how to find out the names/description of the current options.